# How to run multiple feature files using the cucumber runner class?

Tags: selenium, cucumber

Using the below line of code, all scenarios mentioned in login.feature can be executed.

```
@CucumberOptions(features= "src/main/resources/publish/login.feature", format = {"pretty"} )
```

If I have to execute multiple feature files, how do I define? Assuming if I define as below, features mentioned in publish folder would be executed.

```
@CucumberOptions(features= "src/main/resources/publish", format = {"pretty"} )
```

If I have to run multiple features and scenarios inside it, how do I define? Do i have to create multile **cucumberRunner** classes or i can define in one class file.

Comment: Way you have defined will work for all feature files inside this folder including any sub-directories

Comment: How do i test specific scenarios located in different feature files if i give the whole directory? In that case every feature will be executed

Comment: You need to filter using tags... Put approprate tags in your feature files and use them as filter in your runner class using the tags option for cucumberoptions

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how to define tags in cucumber options class and for scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by defining tags value in cucumber option(considering that you have already grouped those scenarios in feature files)

Eg:
                  features="src/test/resources/FeatureFiles",tags="@feature1scenariogroup1,@feature2cenariogroup2"

Defining Tags Inside Feature File:

```
Feature: My Feature File
@smoke 
Scenario: Login
Given I open "FireFox" browser
When I navigate to Sectionone "Home" page
And i do something
Then I Validate Something  

@regression 
Scenario: Compose Email
Given I open "FireFox" browser
When I Do An Action

@OnlyOneTime
Scenario:Send Email
....
```

Comment: How do i give the same tags to the scenarios?

Comment: did you miss any attachment?

Comment: edited my answer showing how to define tags inside feature file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, the below code works for multiple feature files (tags attribute only works when you want to run particular scenario), I tried the below for multiple feature files, it worked:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src\\test\\resources\\cucumberfeaturefolder\\cucumber1.feature",
        "src\\test\\resources\\cucumberfeaturefolder\\cucumber2.feature"},
glue= "StepDef")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use selective feature file or selective scenarios in the feature using tags. Please try with this solution.

Lets consider the you have n number of feature files and you need to run only selective feature from that. Then name each feature file with @tag name.

eg.: Under this folder, if you are having n number of features - "src/main/resources/publish"

1st Feature file name:

Login.feature

//Inside the file start with feature tag name

```
@Login
Feature: To Login to Email

//Then feature name followed with scenario tag name
@User

//Scenario1:    
Scenario Outline: Navigate and logon to gmail application

Given User launches gmail application
When User updates emailID <emailID>
And User updates pwd <pwd>    
Then User clicks on Login Button


Examples: 
  | emailID    | pwd |
  | a@gmail.com| 123 |
```

2nd Feature File name:

CreateEmail.feature

```
 @Createmail
 Feature: Create email

 Scenario: Blah blah blah...

 //Write all Given when And Then
```

3rd Feature File name:

SendEmail.feature

```
 @Sendemail
 Feature: Send email

 Scenario: Blah blah blah...

 //Write all Given when And Then
```

So From the above Test files. Lets consider you want to test 1st and 3rd feature alone, Then you can use code as below:

eg.: # This is to run specific feature files, which is 1 and 3. Likewise you can use the tags for scenario as well if you have n number scenario in same feature file.

```
 @CucumberOptions(features= "src/main/resources/publish", tags="@Login, @Sendemail",  format = {"pretty"} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified my code like to run all enabled features, scenarios. features is the point to note here for the runner class to consider the features

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:features"},
        plugin = {"html:target/site/cucumber-pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},
        tags = {"@currentTest"},
        glue={"helpers","stepDefinitions"},
        //      dryRun = true,
        monochrome = true
        )
public class RunCukesTest{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write tags = {"@fileName1, @fileName2"}

We can add multiple files using @File1, @File2,..

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
features = {"src/test/java/Features"},
tags= {"@FirstTimeLaunch, @SignUpPage"},
glue= {"testCode"},
plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/htmlreports" }
)
```

Here all *.feature files inside your Features folder (Package) will be executed in the Alphabetic order of the file name, when you execute as a Junit test ( runner class )

Answer (score 0):

Following code working for me:

(1) BeerCans.feature

```
Feature: Beer Cans
  Scenario: Counting Beer Cans
    Given I have <opening balance> beer cans
    And I have drunk processed beer cans
    When I go to my fridge
    Then I should have <in stock> beer cans
```

(2) multiplication.feature

```
Feature: Multiplication
  I multiply two numbers
  Scenario: multiple a and b
    Given I have variable a
    And I have variable b
    When I multiply a and b
    Then I display the Result
```

(3) MyStepdefs class

```
package org.example.njain51.steps; /**
 * @author : Nitin Jain
 * @mailto : official.nitinjain@gmail.com
 * @created : 5/22/2022, Sunday
 **/

import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

/**
 What this program snippet doing? 
 **/
public class MyStepdefs {
    @Given("I have <opening balance> beer cans")
    public void iHaveOpeningBalanceBeerCans() {
        System.out.println("I have Opening Balance");
    }

    @And("I have drunk processed beer cans")
    public void iHaveDrunkProcessedBeerCans() {
    }

    @When("I go to my fridge")
    public void iGoToMyFridge() {
        System.out.println("I go to my Fridge");

    }

    @Then("I should have <in stock> beer cans")
    public void iShouldHaveInStockBeetCans() {
        System.out.println("I should have in stock beer cans");
    }


}
```

(4) MultiplicationStepDef class

```
package org.example.njain51.steps; /**
 * @author : Nitin Jain
 * @mailto : official.nitinjain@gmail.com
 * @created : 5/22/2022, Sunday
 **/

import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

/**
 What this program snippet doing?
 **/
public class MultiplicationStepDef {
    @Given("I have variable a")
    public void iHaveVariableA() {
        System.out.println("I have variable a");
    }

    @And("I have variable b")
    public void iHaveVariableB() {
        System.out.println("I have variable b");
    }

    @When("I multiply a and b")
    public void iMultiplyAAndB() {
        System.out.println("I Multiply a and b");
    }


    @Then("I display the Result")
    public void iDispayTheResult() {
        System.out.println("I Display the result");
    }
}
```

(5) RunCucumberTest Class for multiple feature implementation

```
package org.example.njain51;/**
 * @author : Nitin Jain
 * @mailto : official.nitinjain@gmail.com
 * @created : 5/22/2022, Sunday
 **/

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/features/BeerCans.feature",
                   "src/test/resources/features/multiplication.feature"},
        glue = {"org.example.njain51.steps"})
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

(6) Output when I run RunCucumberTest

```
C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\bin\java.exe -ea -DnodeNamesHandler=org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberTestTreeNodeManager -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=49946:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Users\offic\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_292\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\mylearning\SAMPLE_PROJECTS\Testing\cucumber-demo\target\test-classes;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-java\6.1.1\cucumber-java-6.1.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-core\6.1.1\cucumber-core-6.1.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-gherkin\6.1.1\cucumber-gherkin-6.1.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-gherkin-messages\6.1.1\cucumber-gherkin-messages-6.1.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\messages\12.1.1\messages-12.1.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\tag-expressions\3.0.0\tag-expressions-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-expressions\10.2.0\cucumber-expressions-10.2.0.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\datatable\3.3.1\datatable-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-plugin\6.1.1\cucumber-plugin-6.1.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\docstring\6.1.1\docstring-6.1.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\html-formatter\6.0.3\html-formatter-6.0.3.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.0\apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-junit\6.1.1\cucumber-junit-6.1.1.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.13\junit-4.13.jar;C:\Users\offic\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\plugins\cucumber-java\lib\cucumber-jvmFormatter.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 org.example.njain51.RunCucumberTest
I have Opening Balance
I go to my Fridge
I should have in stock beer cans
I have variable a
I have variable b
I Multiply a and b
I Display the result

Process finished with exit code 0
```