# Unable to run multiple feature files together at once

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I want to run multiple feature files first the partyfeatures.feature and next policyfeature.feature , but I am unable to run the second one . Below is my runner class .

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources"},
glue = {"com.cucumber.bhsibase.party.tests"})
public class TestRunner  {

    //runner class

    public static WebDriver driver ; 
       private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

       @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
       public void setUpClass() throws Exception {

           ConfigReader reader = new ConfigReader();

            driver = new FirefoxDriver() ; 
            driver.get(reader.readurls("ExpressURL"));
            testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        }

       @Test(description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
        public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
            testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
        }

       @DataProvider
        public Object[][] features() {
            return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
        }

       @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
           driver.quit();
           testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
        }

}
```

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493401/how-to-run-multiple-feature-files-using-the-Kavi123dilse-class

Comment: Are both the feature files inside the location specified in features option?

Comment: Yes both are in same location .

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? If it's about steps being undefined, could it be the steps for policyfeature are defined in a different file than those for partyfeature (considering you specify `glue = {"com.cucumber.bhsibase.party.tests"}`)