# How to run multiple feature files on same thread

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit, automation, cucumber

i Want to run multiple feature file on the same thread but using below cucumber tags option is not working for ex: tags="@login,@Registration".

Where login has seperate feature file **login.feature** and Registration has seperate feature file **Registration.feature**.

On running above tags im getting blank console output and no errors are displaying..

Help me out to resolve this... Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is this solve your issue    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013315/unable-to-run-multiple-feature-files-together-at-once

Comment: hi Akzy.. not working tried it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"Features/*.feature"},             
        glue="stepDefinition", 
        tags={"@Login","@Registration"})
```

Comment: Hi @irfan.. on trying above syntax im getting error like "Type mismatch cannot convert string[] to string....i tried it already not working for ex: also tried below combinations, 1.tags= {"@login,@Registration"} 2.tags= "@login,@Registration", 3.tags= "@login and @Registration" 4.tags= ["@login,@Registration"].etc..  not working.. if i use seperately tag=@login or tag=@registration -- that is running without any issues and getting output.. but combination of two no luck

Comment: check through official site it might help

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@foo and not @bar"})
public class RunCucumberTest {
}